# Converting a TexSoup tree back to LaTeX

Tags: python, latex

I've been testing a Python module called TexSoup, which I have found very useful in parsing  LaTeX documents. It can also alter their structure and content. However, I haven't been able to transform the resulting TeXSoup object back into a string, which I can output as a LaTeX document.

Say I have the following Python script which strips whitespace from `pagenotes`:

```
from TexSoup import TexSoup
with open("input.tex") as f:
    tex_doc = f.read()
soup = TexSoup(tex_doc)
for n in soup.find_all(r'pagenote'):
    content = n.args[0].string
    n.args[0].string = content.strip()
```

How can I write `soup` back to a file? This doesn't work:

```
with open("out.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup)
```

because `soup` is a TexNode and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

TeXSoup developer has responded to this question in GitHub. He said to simply enclose the TexSoup object in a str():

```
with open("out.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```